# Graph Theory: Maximum subset of tree nodes such that minimum distance is d

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

Given a tree on `n` vertices. Pick the maximum number nodes such that no two of the chosen nodes has distance less than `d`. Output is the number of maximum nodes. Here `n` and `d` can be upto `10^5`. How can it be solved in linear or quasilinear time?

Comment: Please tell us if the answer worked, so that the next people can use it !

Answer (score 0):

Yes :)

- If you take the root, then the optimal is 1 plus the sum of the optimums of the subtrees that are d levels lower.
- Otherwise, it is the sum of the values for the root's children (without +1).

So you should take a bottom-up approach (or recursive WITH MEMOIZATION) computing the optimal value for the subtree of a node. If the node is a leaf, the value is 1. Otherwise, use the rule written above.

You should try to compute each node's value only once, and each node's value is used only for its parent and its d-th grandparent, so you have a complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: Nope. If we mark all childs of some node those childs might be at distance <= d.